# When Google document is copied with container-bound script, how to get its installable triggers?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, triggers, google-docs

### Issue

I have a container-bound script attached to my document.
It has `onOpen` installable trigger and I need to get the script in newly created documents. 
The most effective way I found is to create the new documents by copying from the original document.

**`The problem is, that the triggers are not copied with it.`**

### Conditions:

1. Simple triggers are not enough, I need to use action requiring authorization
2. I don't want to force my users to create manually trigger for each document
3. I don't mind if the installable trigger is created after clicking button from the programmatically created menu

### My thoughts:

I wanted to create it programmatically – there is a problem with the testing environment. I am getting an error:

> The add-on attempted an action that is not permitted in Test as add-on
>   mode. To use this action, you must deploy the add-on.

as I understood, I need to release the project to the store to use this, which I don't want to do.

I don't mind release as an add-on, but the google script IDE only offers to release as web Docs web add-on.

Code:

```
function onOpen(e){
    DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp, SlidesApp, or FormApp.
        .createMenu('Custom menu')
        .addItem('Open sidebar automatically', 'createTrigger')
        .addToUi();
}


function createTrigger() {
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onOpenReal')
        .forDocument(doc)
        .onOpen()
        .create();
}

function onOpenReal(e){
    ...something requiring authorization...
}
```

Comment: If you mean not to test by "test as add-on" button and instead open the doc as regular user, then the error is the same.

Comment: I find out the issue! It was thanks to your first comment. I needed to first delete all my test configurations in "Test as add-on" option. Until that the system saw all launches as "test" even if opened as a regular user. The question is still valid because this solution is worse than if the trigger was copied together with the doc, but if nothing better will show up, I will answer myself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured the answer partially:

I think it is **not possible** to copy the document together with its triggers, but I didn't find any official documentation about that.

**But** the error:

> The add-on attempted an action that is not permitted in Test as add-on
>   mode. To use this action, you must deploy the add-on.

in the seemingly regular environment was caused by saved test configuration in the Google apps script editor.

To get rid of the error you need to first delete all test configurations in "Test as add-on" option. Until that the system sees all launches as "test" even if opened as a regular user.